# IllegalArgumentException when updating from commandButton

Tags: jsf, glassfish

I am trying to create a jsf page that contains two tabs. the first tab contains a selectOnMenu component that needs to be updated when a button in the second tab is clicked.

here are the relevant parts of the xhtml file:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" >  
        <p:tab id="tab1" >  
                <h:form id="form" > 
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="mastersList">
                         <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                         <ui:include  src="/WEB-INF/filling.xhtml" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:dataTable id="exigences" >
                     .
                     .
                     .
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
       </p:tab>
       <p:tab id="tab2" >  
         <h:panelGrid>
            <h:form>
               <p:dataTable id="masters">
                     .
                     .
                     .
               </p:dataTable>
                <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer"  update="masters , :tabView:tab1:form:mastersList" />
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGrid>  
       </p:tab>
     </p:tabView>
```

but upon running the above code , I get an IllegalArgumentException in the glassfish server log :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tab1
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:655)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:245)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addIds(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:102)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:90)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:200)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:75)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:50)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:279)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:237)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I don't think the id sequence in the update is wrong. what could be the problem? thanks in advance for any help

Comment: remove tab1 in your update statement update="masters,:tabView:form:mastersList"

Comment: Thnks , the error disappeared , but the component was not update with the new values

Comment: I think the update I want to make amounts to reloading the "filling.xhtml" file. is it possible to do that?

Comment: Instead of updating on button click you can do the same when Tab1 is clicked. you can use tabchange event of p:tabView and do whatever you want. Add this as a child element of p:tabView <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{myActionHere}" />